# Is it possible to bypass the 5-second delay in EFI shell?

Tags: boot, uefi, efi

Due to my unusual hardware configuration (see [Graphics card not working on Windows 8.1 on Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/671660/graphics-card-not-working-on-windows-8-1-on-mac)), i am forced to set two PCI registers using the `mm` EFI command before being able to boot Windows. Right now i have a build of the EFI shell (my mobo does not have one built-in) dropped as `bootx64.efi` with `startup.nsh` looking like this:

```
mm 0010003E 1 ;PCI :8
mm 02000004 1 ;PCI :7
fs0:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
```

Would it be possible to replace the EFI shell with something more lightweight that would preferably NOT allow interrupting the boot process?

Answer (score 2):

Were you performing an EFI boot of Windows on a Mac? I've just accomplished the same thing on my Mid-2009 MacBook Pro 5,4

My EFI shell is also non-firmware. I had to put it in the EFI partition and `bless` it manually.. Still I was able to use `Set StartupDelay [X]` My EFI shell is the `Precompiled x86_64 UEFI Shell v1 binary` found at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Obtaining_UEFI_Shell or more directly: https://svn.code.sf.net/p/edk2/code/trunk/edk2/EdkShellBinPkg/FullShell/X64/Shell_Full.efi
I am using the v1 rather than the v2 because v2 is described as being more useful on UEFI (v2) systems unlike my Mac which uses 1.10 EFI firmware.

With that, `Set StartupDelay [x]` works for me, but **don't put it in your startup.nsh**! You only need to invoke it once. Otherwise, you will needlessly rewrite your NVRAM after every boot, reducing its lifespan needlessly. 
I haven't tried '0' for a startup value. I just needed a smaller delay. For me, my startup.nsh starts Refind. I need to have some time to bypass it if I'm starting the shell from refind. Although, refind has a shell accessible by exiting refind, and there is no nsh startup issued within it.. I am not sure if this shell is enabled by having shell.efi tool, or if it was always there.

`help set -b` shows good info on the `set` command. It states that if there is no NVRAM environment associated with the shell, it will save the variables into 
  /efi/boot/bootstr.nvr, which means the command should work for anyone without NVRAM.
but that file is never created on my machine, so it's definitely in NVRAM. I proved it by using 
  `dmpstore StartupDelay`
which dumps the NVRAM variables (in this case, only for StartupDelay, if it exists)

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is on a Mac. See http://superuser.com/questions/671660/graphics-card-not-working-on-windows-8-1-on-mac (same OP).

Comment: Can’t check it, since i’m not using that computer anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate the startup delay by putting "set StartupDelay 0" at the beginning of your startup.nsh, where 0 is the number of seconds to wait. This worked for me.

Comment: I do not have the EFI shell in my firmware, so it did not work for me.