# Windows 10 crash with Nvidia 9400 driver installation iMac late 2009

Tags: windows, mac, drivers, efi

I know that the problem has already been addressed but in my case by following the various guides on the net I can not solve it. 
I successfully installed Windows 10 on a late 2009 iMac
and the only thing I couldn't get to work is
installing the drivers for the Nvidia 9400 video card.

I have tried with different versions from the Nvidia site,
but every time I run the setup after a few seconds Windows reboots unexpectedly.

I tried with refind to create a startup.nsh script with these instructions right:

```
mm 0010003E 1; PCI: 8
mm 03000004 1; PCI: 7
fs0:EFI\Microsoft\Boot\Bootmgfw.efi
```

I am afraid that these addresses in my case are ignored;
perhaps they are not correct.

Here is the link where the problem was solved with these:

[Graphics card not working on Windows 8.1 on Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/671660/graphics-card-not-working-on-windows-8-1-on-mac)

Can anyone help me figure out what the PCI addresses are for my model?

Here is some information taken with my EFI shell:

```
Seg  Bus  Dev  Func
---  ---  ---  ----
 00   00   00    00 ==> Bridge Device - Host/PCI bridge
          Vendor 10DE Device 0A80 Prog Interface 0
 00   00   00    01 ==> Memory Controller - RAM memory controller
          Vendor 10DE Device 0A88 Prog Interface 0

 00   00   03    00 ==> Bridge Device - PCI/ISA bridge
          Vendor 10DE Device 0AAC Prog Interface 0
 00   00   03    01 ==> Memory Controller - RAM memory controller
          Vendor 10DE Device 0AA4 Prog Interface 0
 00   00   03    02 ==> Serial Bus Controllers - System Management Bus
          Vendor 10DE Device 0AA2 Prog Interface 0
 00   00   03    03 ==> Memory Controller - RAM memory controller
          Vendor 10DE Device 0A89 Prog Interface 0
 00   00   03    04 ==> Memory Controller - RAM memory controller
          Vendor 10DE Device 0A98 Prog Interface 0
 00   00   03    05 ==> Processors - Co-processor
          Vendor 10DE Device 0AA3 Prog Interface 0

 00   00   04    00 ==> Serial Bus Controllers - USB
          Vendor 10DE Device 0AA5 Prog Interface 10
 00   00   04    01 ==> Serial Bus Controllers - USB
          Vendor 10DE Device 0AA6 Prog Interface 20

 00   00   06    00 ==> Serial Bus Controllers - USB
          Vendor 10DE Device 0AA7 Prog Interface 10




 00   00   06    01 ==> Serial Bus Controllers - USB
          Vendor 10DE Device 0AA9 Prog Interface 20

 00   00   08    00 ==> Multimedia Device - UNDEFINED
          Vendor 10DE Device 0AC0 Prog Interface 0
 00   00   09    00 ==> Bridge Device - PCI/PCI bridge
          Vendor 10DE Device 0AAB Prog Interface 1
 00   00   0A    00 ==> Network Controller - Ethernet controller
          Vendor 10DE Device 0AB0 Prog Interface 0
 00   00   0B    00 ==> Mass Storage Controller - UNDEFINED
          Vendor 10DE Device 0AB9 Prog Interface 1
 00   00   0C    00 ==> Bridge Device - PCI/PCI bridge
          Vendor 10DE Device 0AC4 Prog Interface 0

 00   00   10    00 ==> Bridge Device - PCI/PCI bridge
          Vendor 10DE Device 0AA0 Prog Interface 0
 00   00   15    00 ==> Bridge Device - PCI/PCI bridge
          Vendor 10DE Device 0AC6 Prog Interface 0
 00   00   16    00 ==> Bridge Device - PCI/PCI bridge
          Vendor 10DE Device 0AC7 Prog Interface 0

 00   03   00    00 ==> Display Controller - VGA/8514 controller
          Vendor 10DE Device 0869 Prog Interface 0
 00   04   00    00 ==> Network Controller - other network controller
          Vendor 168C Device 002A Prog Interface 0
 00   05   00    00 ==> Bridge Device - PCI/PCI bridge
          Vendor 104C Device 823E Prog Interface 0
```

**Manually transcribed** from these photographs ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nE9Y.jpg), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKRAE.jpg))
with blank lines added for readability.

Answer (score 0):

The iMac 09 is only qualified for maximum Win7 32-bit (Ref: [EveryMac](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-2-duo-2.66-24-inch-aluminum-early-2009-specs.html)). The only way usually to get around this is install Boot Camp with Win7/32 then upgrade it.
The last Win10 drivers for the 9600 were way back in 2016. It's a legacy card.

I doubt an EFI mode Windows install would be a good idea on such an old Mac. Use Boot Camp to install as legacy, protected MBR, for Win7 & then for your upgrade.

Comment: Yes, I know that it is an old hardware for windows 10 but I have seen that many people have succeeded in the enterprise.
In fact, I also managed to install it in the end and it is fully functional. The only problem is that of the video card which can be solved through VGA support for EFI
I repeat, for many it worked even if for macbooks of the same year. Unfortunately mine has other PCI addresses and I can't correctly construct the values to insert in the script

Answer (score 0):

I already answer [on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/jmsy9r/mac_windows_10_problem/gw61ad4?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), here it's a copy

I have a late 2009 iMac, an iMac 10,1 with nvidia 9400m.

After 2 days of trying to fix this problem it's good!

[Here](http://Here) you have a guide for installing Windows 10 but it's for a Macbook Pro 2009.

In the 4.4 step the guy indicate a code who is not the right for iMac 10,1.

To find the right code, i read and adapt [Wayne Uroda's](https://superuser.com/users/63570/wayne-uroda) answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/671660/graphics-card-not-working-on-windows-8-1-on-mac/1544479#1544479) (the last answer) it's very complete and give you all the key to adapt the code correctly!

So because i didn't found any trace of this code for iMac 10,1 with nvidia 9400m

il will give it here:

```
mm 0003000004 ;PCI :3
mm 000016003E ;PCI :8
fs0:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
```

Make a fresh windows 10 install without internet connection and after you get everything booting correctly you will be able to install the last NVIDIA driver.

Answer (score 0):

On my **MacBook Late 2009 (Macbook6,1 or a1342)** the correct code for **startup.nsh** was:

```
mm 000015003E ;PCI :8
mm 0002000004 ;PCI :7
fs0:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
```

[The detailed explanation of this is here](https://superuser.com/a/1702940/1664408)